# [EntLib 5]: Logging between assemblies

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, enterprise-library-5

I've got a project that I'm working Enterprise Library logging into, and that application is made up of multiple assemblies. The UI assembly, the domain assembly and some others. Is there a way to have the logging all go to the same location (in the case of rolling flat file)?

**Edit>** Now that I look at it further, *can* you even use EntLib loggin in a class library? None of the setup that I've used thus far is available because of a lack of an app.config for a class library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, multiple assemblies can log to the same file provided that they are all running in the same app domain.

For configuration you can use the `FileConfigurationSource` and use the factory method `LogWriterFactory(IConfigurationSource)` to create a `LogWriter`.  See [External configuration files in Enterprise Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tomholl/external-configuration-files-in-enterprise-library-for-net-framework-2-0) for more information.

An alternative approach would be to forgo file based configuration and use [programmatic configuration](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/02/18/2805.aspx).